# Unable to see certain Unicode characters

Tags: fonts, unicode

I am not able to see any of the characters in the "ornamental dingbats" section of the Unicode Standard (see [here](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-7.0/U70-1F650.pdf)).  These were apparently added to the standard in June 2014.  How can I correct this?  Is there some package I can install?  I have tried two computers, one running Arch Linux and the other Linux Mint.  Solutions for Mac OS and Windows would also be welcome.

Comment: You want too much, you need fonts which have them

Comment: @RomeoNinov, can you explain?  How do I get such fonts?

Comment: Ask Apple and Ubuntu for them. As they are added quite soon you can expect such fonts in the middle of the year or later